# Aggregation on id and append different values in different columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like below:

```
id  c1   c2       c3
1   5    text1    -4
2   8    text2    -1
1   4    text1     0
2   7    text2    -8
3   2    text3    -5
1   2    text1    -8
...
```

then, this is my desire output:

```
id    c2       c3   c4  c5
1     text1    -4   0   -8
2     text2    -1  -8
3     text3    -5
...
```

, i tried this piece of code,

```
  df.groupby(['id','c2']).cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
g = df.groupby(['id','c2']).cumcount().add(3)
df = df.set_index(['id','c2', g])['c3'].unstack().add_prefix('c').reset_index()
print (df)
   id     c2   c3   c4   c5
0   1  text1 -4.0  0.0 -8.0
1   2  text2 -1.0 -8.0  NaN
2   3  text3 -5.0  NaN  NaN
```

If need replace `NaN` by `0`:

```
g = df.groupby(['id','c2']).cumcount().add(3)
df = df.set_index(['id','c2', g])['c3'].unstack(fill_value=0).add_prefix('c').reset_index()
print (df)
   id     c2  c3  c4  c5
0   1  text1  -4   0  -8
1   2  text2  -1  -8   0
2   3  text3  -5   0   0
```